# Web scraping from google scholar with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Searching in Google Scholar the string "electronic knee" I retrieve about 14.000 results.
Here is the link:
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=10&q=electronic+knee&hl=it&as_sdt=8,5&as_ylo=2017&as_rr=1

Is it possible to obtain the results number (that are at the beginning of the page) through web scraping in python? I'm using bs4 (find_all function to get strings) library to retrieve results from each record but I would like to get the total number of results. What is the tag or is there another method?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Comment: what do you use to get HTML from server - `requests` or `selenium`? Google may send different code if you run `requests` which can't run JavaScritpt or `selenium` which can run JavaScript - and then it may display it in different tag. It may also use different classes in tags for different users or devices - all to stop spamers/hackers/bots/scripts. Google should have API for developers.

Comment: in Firefox this value is in tag `div` but there is many other `div` in HTML and you should rather use classes or IDs to search elements. And you can use chained `find(...).find(...)` to use more complex rules to get it. OR you can use `select()` or `xpath()` to create more complex rules

Answer (score 0):

This value is inside `div` with `id="gs_ab_md"` (at least on my computer)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=10&q=electronic+knee&hl=it&as_sdt=8,5&as_ylo=2017&as_rr=1'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

item = soup.find('div', {'id': 'gs_ab_md'})
print(item.text)
```

Result:

```
Pagina 2 di circa 14.400 risultati (0,02 sec)
```

---

And later you can use string functions to get only `14.440`

For example

```
parts = item.text.split(' ')
print(parts[4])
```

Result:

```
14.400
```